# Mercurial - hg command line to list all files from a specific rev

Tags: mercurial, command-line-arguments, tortoisehg

I'm a new mercurial user, and i 've got a specific needs on my project.

I would like to know if there's an easy way to list every files from a project rev and for each file, get the reversion version.

For example :

```
rev 100
-toto.c rev 3
-toto.h rev 50
-tata.c rev 100
```

Thanks in advance if someone got an idea :)

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail please? What exactly do you mean when you say you want to get the file revision version? Do you mean the last revision it was changed in before this one? The number of time it has been changed over the lifetime of the repository? Or something else?

Comment: Hi Nanhydrin.
I mean, for a specific rev (or the latest one) i would like to know every files from the project and for each file, got the rev associated.

For example if the latest version is rev 345, i would like to know : In this rev we've got toto.c from rev345, tata.c from 300. 
But if i check for rev300, i should have : toto.c from 140 and tata.c from 300.

When i say that i would like to have the rev from each file, it means the latest version corresponding to the rev i'm checking for.

Hmmm ... not sur that the explication is detailed enough ... Is that ok ? :)

Comment: Ok, so you're not looking for details on the files that were changed in that revision only, you're looking for the details of every file in the repository at that point and in what revision it was last modified. Also it would be helpful to show us what you've already tried and what results you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A file in Hg doesn't have a specific revision number associated with it
("the most recent revision in which this file was changed")
A single file can have multiple "most recent versions" in different branches.

This command lists all files in a certain revision:

[hg Manifest](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Manifest)

hg manifest [-r REV]

output the current or given revision of the project manifest

Comment: Thanks it's the first command i'm using in my batchfile but i need to know for each file the current version linked to the rev i'm checking for ...  Perhaps a hg log "filename"

Comment: `hg log -r "max(filelog(MYFILE.TXT))"` gives you the highest revisionnumber including a change in MYFILE.TXT

Comment: look in `hg help revsets` for more posibilities

Answer (score 0):

manifest and log was the two commands i used in my batchfile but i have to do some test because following my understanding there is a probleme :

The rev is 10, into this rev there is a file test.c which has been changed in rev 5 and 10. If i apply manifest and log commands on it i will have test.c in my files list and the rev of test.c will be 10. 
The problem is, if i understand good enough, when i will ask the manifest for rev5, i will also have test.c in my list of files but when i will apply a log on it it will give me only the latest version of that file ... so rev10. 
Even if in rev 5 my file has an oldest version ... 
I will take some time today to do some test :)

Thanks for your advices

Answer (score 0):

You could combine manifest and log to obtain your stated list:

```
for i in `hg ma`; do hg log -l1 $i --template="$i: {rev}\n"; done
```

It will list the latest change to each file found in the currently checked out revision. If you want all files ever found in the repository (even when they are not there anymore) you could give the --all flag for manifest. And maybe add --follow and --removed to log.

Comment: Hmm good one, i was using this kind of batchfile for now :  
`hg manifest > tmp.txt`
`for /F %%G in (tmp.txt) do ( echo %%G >>test.txt & hg log -f -l 1 "%%G" >>test.txt )`
`del tmp.txt`